# Помогите с сохранением div'а как png (с прозрачностью!)

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, javascript

Суть такая, есть сторонний вебсайт с которого нужно стянуть изображения, которые генерируются налету путём хитрого совмещения составных частей с добавлением CSS.

Я бы мог взять инструмент "ножницы", но не о какой прозрачности не могло бы быть и речи. И в тоже время я не хочу брать какой-нибудь браузерный движок и рендерить всё это дело вручную а потом сохранять.

Есть ли плагины или более элегантный способ с помощью какой-нибудь JS библиотеки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Есть либа, которая осуществляет рендеринг средствами javascript.
  https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas
  Полагаю прозрачность сохранится. В случае снимков экрана будет подставлен фон и прозрачности не будет.
- можно поизучить работу сайта http://bugmuncher.com/

Comment: Работал как-то с первой библиотекой на одном из проектов, в целом то, что нужно. Протестирую её :)